# How to mask clouds and shadows for Landsat 5 Collection 2 Level 2 data in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, cloudmasking

I want to create a cloud-free composite for Landsat 5 data and I want the shadows to be masked as well. However, the code only includes the clouds. I am extremely new to this and cannot find any reference codes for Landsat 5 Collection 2 Level 2 data specifically. How do I fix this?

```
  // AOI
var aoi = table;

// Landsat 5
var landsat5 = l5.filterBounds(aoi)
  .filterDate('2009-11-01', '2009-11-02') 
  .map(cloudMaskLandsat5)
  .median()
  .multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2)
  .clip(aoi);

Map.addLayer(landsat5, {bands: ['SR_B4', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B2'], min: 0, max: [0.5, 0.3, 0.2]}, 'Landsat 5');

// Landsat 5 cloud mask
function cloudMaskLandsat5(image){
  var qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL');  
  var cloud = 1 << 5;
  var shadow = 1 << 3;  
  
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloud).eq(0)
    .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(shadow).eq(0));
    
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the bit-mask for `QA_PIXEL` in the [catalog](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LT05_C02_T1_L2#bands):

> ```
> Bit 0: Fill
> Bit 1: Dilated Cloud
> Bit 2: Unused
> Bit 3: Cloud
> Bit 4: Cloud Shadow
> Bit 5: Snow
> Bit 6: Clear
>     0: Cloud or Dilated Cloud bits are set
>     1: Cloud and Dilated Cloud bits are not set
> Bit 7: Water
> Bits 8-9: Cloud Confidence
>     0: None
>     1: Low
>     2: Medium
>     3: High
> Bits 10-11: Cloud Shadow Confidence
>     0: None
>     1: Low
>     2: Medium
>     3: High
> Bits 12-13: Snow/Ice Confidence
>     0: None
>     1: Low
>     2: Medium
>     3: High
> Bits 14-15: Cirrus Confidence
>     0: None
>     1: Low
>     2: Medium
>     3: High
> ```

You've used bit `3` and `5` - that's cloud and snow. Include bit `4` for cloud shadow in the same manner.